# C#でインターフェースから本体のクラスの参照を得る方法ないですか

Tags: c#

```
class Derived : Base, IInterface1, IInterface2 {
}
```

みたいなクラスが定義されている時に IInterface1 の参照から Derived の参照を得る方法はないでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

「参照」が何を指すかはっきりしませんが、

```
IInterface1 obj;
```

のようなインターフェイスの型を持つインスタンス参照がある場合、`Derived`型の変数は

```
Derived d = (Derived)obj;
```

のように得られます。

また動的に型情報が欲しい場合は`obj.GetType()`の結果を参照します。

`Type`から`Type`を得たい場合は

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain
         .GetAssemblies()
         .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
         .Where(t => typeof(IInterface1).IsAssignableFrom(t))
```

のように`Assembly.GetTypes`から検索できます。